# The view videos.views.add_comment_post didn't return an HttpResponse object. with the second object in Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I try to build a blog and this blog consist of posts and these posts have comments, When I add comment to the first post it adds succussfuly but when I try to add comment the second or third this error raise
**ValueError: The view videos.views.add_comment_post didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**

and I tried to add comment form to the template without any widgets `commentForm = PostCommentForm()` to the template `{{commentForm }}`  and I filled it and this proplem still

My Post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    photo_article = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=get_poster_filepath)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class PostCommentIDF(MPTTModel):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,    related_name='children')
    author = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

My create comments view

```
@login_required
def add_comment_post(request):
    if not request.user.is_active:
        return render(request, 'personal/violated.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('action') == 'delete':
            id = request.POST.get('nodeid')
            c = PostCommentIDF.objects.get(id=id)
            c.delete()

            return JsonResponse({'remove': id})
        else:
            comment_form = PostCommentForm(request.POST)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                user_comment.author = request.user
                user_comment.save()
                result = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('content')
                user = request.user.username

                return JsonResponse({'result': result, 'user': user})
```

My comments Form

```
class PostCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
class Meta:
    model = PostCommentIDF
    fields = {'post', 'content'}
    widgets = {
        'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': ' form-control', 'rows': '1', 'placeholder': 'Comment', 'required': 'True', })
    }
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    PostCommentIDF.objects.rebuild()
    return super(PostCommentForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

my home template

```
{% for video in video %}
   ....
 <form id="Postcommentform" class="Postcommentform" method="post" style="width: 100%;">
     {% load mptt_tags %}
     {% csrf_token %}
<

select class="d-none" name="video" id="id_video">
        <option value="{{ video.id }}" selected="{{ video.id }}"></option></select>
      <div class="d-flex">
   <label class="small font-weight-bold">{{ comments.parent.label }}</label>
            {{ comments.parent }}
          {{comments.content}}
 <button value="Postcommentform" id="Postnewcomment" type="submit"  style="color: white; border-radius: 0;" class="d-flex justify-content-end btn btn-primary">Post</button>
               </div>
          </form>
       ....
    {% endfor %}
```

My ajax for add posts

```
    myCommentForm = document.getElementById("Postcommentform")

$(document).on('click', '#Postnewcomment, #Postnewcommentinner', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var button = $(this).attr("value");

  var placement = "Postcommentform"
  if (button == "Postnewcommentform") {
     var placement = "becomm"
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{% url "video:addcomment_post" %}',
    data: $("#" + button).serialize(),
    cache: false,
    success: function (json) {
      console.log(json);

      $('<div id="" class="my-2 p-2" style="border: 1px solid grey"> \
        <div class="d-flex bd-highlight mb-3">\
         <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">' + json['user'] + '</div> <div class="ml-auto p-2 bd-highlight">Posted: Just now!</div> \
         </div>\
         <div>' + json['result'] + '</div> \
         <br>\
         </div>').insertAfter('becomm' + placement);
         
         document.getElementById("Postcommentform").reset();
       },
       
      error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {

    }
  });
})
```

Comment: show the full code of add_comment_post view

Comment: Hello I updated my qustion

Comment: You haven't returned any  response if the form turns out to be invalid. In fact you should also return a response for GET requests even if it is just a 404 or a 403.

Comment: How I can let the form to not turns out, because I can add comment to the first post but I can't with the second or third

Comment: just add  this in the end of this view ```return JsonResponse({'result': "No action took"})``` this will solve the issue mentioned in the post..

Comment: @Sumithran Thank you it raise this "No action took" . How I can add comment to any post not just to the first post

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat it is show in the terminal  `"POST /video/post/add/comment HTTP/1.1" 500 70598`

Comment: check your form is valid or not?

Comment: @Sumithran yes, it is strange problem because I can add comment to the first post and this shows in the console `{result: "comment", user: "user"}`  but I can't add to the second and when I add this shows in the console `{result: "No action took"}`

Comment: show your request data for "first" and "second" data

Comment: comment of the first post `{result: "first post", user: "user"}` the data of any another post `{result: "No action took"}`